# Bash "-e" puzzler

Tags: bash

I’m trying to build a command string based to pass in a “-e” flag and another variable into a another base script being call as a subroutine and have run into a strange problem; I’m losing the “-e” portion of the string when I pass it into the subroutine.  I create a couple example which illustrate the issue, any help?

This works as you would expect:

```
$echo "-e  $HOSTNAME"

-e  ops-wfm
```

This does NOT; we lose the “-e” because it is interpreted as a special qualifier.

```
$myFlag="-e $HOSTNAME"; echo $myFlag

ops-wfm
```

Adding the “\” escape charactor doesn’t work either, I get the correct string with the "\" in front:

```
$myFlag="\-e $HOSTNAME"; echo $myFlag

\-e ops-wfm
```

How can I prevent `-e` being swallowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use double-quotes:

```
$ myFlag="-e $HOSTNAME"; echo "${myFlag}"
-e myhost.local
```

I use [`${var}`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) rather than `$var` out of habit as it means that I can add characters after the variable without the shell interpreting them as part of the variable name.

`echo` may not be the best example here. Most Unix commands will accept [`--` to mark no more switches](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean).

```
$ var='-e .bashrc' ; ls -l -- "${var}"
ls: -e .bashrc: No such file or directory
```

Comment: thx for the tip; I'm testing in the bash script.what does the {} do for the function?

Comment: Johnsyweb, your detailed response gave me the lead I needed to solve, thanks. Turns out the echo artifact was a red herring and not the real problem. In the original call I was using "$myFlag" which was causing the sub to return an error "option requires an argument -- e". I updated to use the {} format (changed "$myFlag" to ${myFlag}) and bingo it worked.  Not sure why the first format casues a error in the mandatory OPTARG requirement. Thanks PC

Comment: @chesnutp, without being able to see the real code, probably what's happening is that without the quotes, your variable is subject to word splitting, so the program will receive words "-e" and "value", and with double quotes, the program received the single word "-e value".

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could put your variable in quotes:

```
echo "$myFlag"
```

...making it equivalent to your first example, which, as you say, works just fine.